# Where would I ask about xbox 1?

Tags: support, allowed-questions, gaming-hardware

Where would I ask a question about my Xbox 1? I looked at the desc of all the Stack Exchange sites but none said anything about Xbox. (none of the tags really describe this question.)

So should I ask my question here? If not do you know where I can? (preferable on the Stack exchange network.)

Answer (score 7):

Well that depends on the question you have about your xbox 1.

If you want to know how to port-forward it, or how to configure your tv to work with it, you may want to try superuser. But if you have questions about games or xbox 1 specific things then your best bet is probably asking here (well, the main-site)

Comment: Configuring network settings may be here too, if it's "I already have wifi where do I set up the network" (but that's probably in the initial setup menu when you first start I don't know I don't have an xbox one)

Comment: My Xbox is having some sort of issue causing it to auto shutdown almost immediately after boot. but I didn´t know where to ask that question or this question. So i just put it here cause It was the best option. where it is least out of place.

Comment: @USSVoyager asking Arqade would be appropriate then :-)

Comment: I'm not sure about asking Xbox One-related topics to Super User. [Super User's Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) explicitly mentions that "video games or consoles" are off-topic there.